# Is any splitting field algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering whether every splitting field $L$ of some polynomial $f$ over $K$ is an algebraic extension. It seems like so, because the splitting field is constructed via $K[X] / fK[X]$ (w.l.o.g. $f$ irreducible), but I'm not sure how to prove it in detail.

Does anyone know how to prove this in a short and nice manner? Or is there a counterexample of this fact being not true?

Comment: Actually, $K[X] / (f)$ may not be a splitting field for $f$.

Comment: It is algebraic, because it is a finite extension. The degree is bounded from above by $n!$, where $n=\deg f(X)$. Adjoining the first root gives a degree $\le n$ extension, and you can then factor out of that root from $f(X)$. Then proceed by induction on $\deg f(X)$.

Comment: @Jyrki: Very nice!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what if I take a collection of polynomials of unbounded degree will it be an algebraic extension?

Comment: Sure @BiplabDas. It will still be an algebraic extension. Every element in it can only depend on the zeros of finitely many of those polynomials (a polynomial equation can only have finitely many terms), so it reduces to the finite case.

Answer (score 4):

A splitting field, by definition, is generated by the roots of $f$, and by definition these roots are algebraic elements over $K$. Now it's a theorem that in a field generated by algebraic elements, every element is algebraic.